# Help me understand the word "spiegargliele"

Tags: pronouns, compounds

Here is the full sentence: "Bisogna sempre
spiegargliele le cose, ai grandi."

The word "spiegargliele" confuses me. 
First, I know it comes from spiegare.

But what does "glie" stand for? 
Does the indirect object pronoun "loro" transform into "glie" inside a verb? And also, why is there "le" if it is followed by "le cose"?

I translate it as "Explain them (ai grandi) them (le cose) the things". What doesn't really make sense is the presence of "le" if "le cose" is mentioned afterwards?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: These are called "[redundant pronouns](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-personali-ridondanti-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/)" and are used for emphasis in oral speech.

Comment: In fact, “gli(e)” is in the same way redundant with respect to “ai grandi”, but so is life, and Italian language, and other languages, among which English itself. Just think – but I'm sure there are better examples – about a sentence such as “It is nice to walk along the sea”. One could say: why do we say “it” if “to walk...” is mentioned immediately afterwards? Why don't we always say just “To walk... is nice”? Part of the answer is in the concepts of “topic” and “comment”, or “theme” and “rheme” (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_and_comment).

Answer (score 6):

Your translation is correct, and your assumption about "gli" is correct, too. This kind of suffix formed with a pronoun in Italian is called [clitico](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitico).

The whole phrase becomes:

"Bisogna sempre" = it is always necessary

"spiegare (to explain) + "gli" = a loro (to them) + "le" = le cose (the things)

Why "le cose" is repeated as "le" has the same function in the sentence? Well, as Charo wrote in the comments, it is a kind of redundancy typical of spoken language to achieve emphasis. In fact, as said by DaG in his comment,  “gli(e)” is in the same way redundant with respect to “ai grandi”.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what is explained in @RiccardoDeContardi's answer, notice that, as it's explained by Federica Colombo in her book *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri*

> indirect object pronouns ***gli*** and ***le*** + direct object pronouns ***lo***, ***la***, ***li***, ***le*** and the pronominal particle ***ne*** become respectively  ***glielo***, ***gliela***, ***glieli***,  ***gliele*** and ***gliene***.

This book also explains that

> With a verb at infinitive, gerund or imperative (but not the imperative of the courtesy forms) these and other combinations of two pronouns follow the verb and are written attached to it. For instance,
>
> - Ricordati di dar**gliele**!
> - Trovando**melo** davanti, l'ho dovuto salutare.
> - Portate**celo** qui!
> - Da**mmelo**!

You should also know that

> With modal verbs, these combinations of pronouns can have two possible positions: they may precede the conjugated modal verb or they may be written attached at the end of the infinitive. For instance, you may both write
>
> - **Glielo** devi restituire.
> - Devi restituir**glielo**.

(Quoted texts are free translations of the information contained in the above mentioned book.)